# NSUndoManager custom coalescing changes to NSTextField results in crash

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, appkit, nsundomanager

I have a basic Cocoa app using NSUndoManager to support undo/redo. My data model's title can be updated by editing an `NSTextField`. Out of the box NSTextField supports coalescing changes into a single "Undo Typing" undo action so that when the user presses Cmd-Z, the text is reverted in full instead of only the last letter.

I'd like to have a single "Undo Changing Model Title" undo action that undoes multiple changes to my model's title (made in a NSTextField). I tried grouping changes myself, but my app crashes (see below).

I can't use the default undo behavior of NSTextField, because I need to update my model and the text field might be gone by the time the user tries to undo an action (the text field is in a popup window).

NSUndoManager by default groups changes that occur within a single run loop cycle, but also allows to disable this behavior and to create custom "undo groups". So I tried the following:

1. Set `undoManager.groupsByEvent = false`
2. In `controlTextDidBeginEditing()`, begin a new undo group
3. In `controlTextDidChange()`, register an undo action
4. In `controlTextDidEndEditing()`, end the undo group

This works as long as I end editing the text field by pressing Enter. If I type "abc" and press Cmd-Z to undo before ending editing, the app crashes, because the undo grouping was not closed:

```
[General] undo: NSUndoManager 0x60000213b1b0 is in invalid state, undo was called
with too many nested undo groups
```

From the docs, `undo()` is supposed to close the undo grouping automatically, if needed. The grouping level is 1 in my case.

> **undo()** [...] This method also invokes endUndoGrouping() if the nesting level is 1

However, the undo group is not closed by undo(), no matter if I set `groupsByEvent` to true or false. My app always crashes.

What is interesting:

I observed the default behavior of NSTextField. When I type the first letter, it begins AND ends an undo group right away. It does not create any other undo groups for subsequent changes after the first change.

To reproduce:

1. Create a new Cocoa project and paste in the code for the App Delegate (see below)
2. Type "a" + "b" + "c" + Cmd-Z

Expected:

- Text field value should be set to empty string

Actual:

- Crash

Alternatively:

1. Type "a" + "b" + "c" + Enter + Cmd-Z

Result:

- The above works, because this time, the undo group is ended. All grouped changes are undone properly.

The problem is that the user can press Cmd-Z at any time while editing. I can't end the undo group after each change or changes cannot be undone all at once.

undo() not closing the undo group might be a bug, but nonetheless, grouping changes and undoing while typing must be possible, because that's what NSTextField does out of the box (and it works).

Source:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    private var textField:NSTextField!

    private let useCustomUndo = true

    private var myModelTitle = ""

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        //useCustomUndo = false

        observeUndoManger()

        setup()

        NSLog("Window      undo manager: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(window.undoManager!).toOpaque())")
        NSLog("NSTextField undo manager: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(textField.undoManager!).toOpaque())")
    }

    func controlTextDidBeginEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        NSLog("Did begin editing & starting undo group")

        // With or without grouping the app crashes on undo if the group was not ended:
        window.undoManager?.groupsByEvent = true

        window.undoManager?.beginUndoGrouping()
    }

    func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        NSLog("Did end editing & ending undo group")

        window.undoManager?.endUndoGrouping()
    }

    func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
        NSLog("Text did change")

        setModelTitleWithUndo(title: textField.stringValue)
    }

    private func setModelTitleWithUndo(title:String) {
        NSLog("Current groupingLevel: \(window.undoManager!.groupingLevel)")

        window.undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: {[oldValue = myModelTitle, weak self] _  in

           guard let self = self, let undoManager = self.window.undoManager else { return }

           NSLog("\(undoManager.isUndoing ? "Undo" : "Redo") from current model    : '\(self.myModelTitle)' to: '\(oldValue)'")
           NSLog(                                      "     from current textfield: '\(self.textField.stringValue)' to: '\(oldValue)'")

            self.setModelTitleWithUndo(title: oldValue)
        })

        window.undoManager?.setActionName("Change Title")

        myModelTitle = title

        if window.undoManager?.isUndoing ?? false || window.undoManager?.isRedoing ?? false
        {
            textField.stringValue = myModelTitle
        }

        NSLog("Model: '\(myModelTitle)'")
    }

    private func observeUndoManger() {
        for i in [(NSNotification.Name.NSUndoManagerCheckpoint       , "<checkpoint>"          ),
                  (NSNotification.Name.NSUndoManagerDidOpenUndoGroup , "<did open undo group>" ),
                  (NSNotification.Name.NSUndoManagerDidCloseUndoGroup, "<did close undo group>"),
                  (NSNotification.Name.NSUndoManagerDidUndoChange    , "<did undo change>"     ),
                  (NSNotification.Name.NSUndoManagerDidRedoChange    , "<did redo change>"     )]
        {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: i.0, object: nil, queue: nil) {n in

                let undoManager = n.object as! UndoManager

                NSLog("\(Unmanaged.passUnretained(undoManager).toOpaque()) \(i.1) grouping level: \(undoManager.groupingLevel), groups by event: \(undoManager.groupsByEvent)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func setup() {
       textField = NSTextField(string: myModelTitle)
       textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

       window.contentView!.addSubview(textField)

       textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.contentView!.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
       textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.contentView!.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
       textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.contentView!.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

       if useCustomUndo
       {
           textField.cell?.allowsUndo = false
           textField.delegate = self
       }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I observed the behavior of NSTextField some more. NSTextField does *not* group across multiple run loop cycles. NSTextField groups by event and uses `groupsByEvent = true`. It creates a new undo group when I type the first letter, closes the group, and does *not* create any additional undo groups for the next letters I type. Very strange...

Comment: So maybe it just adds initial state to the undo stack for the first change checkpoint?